# Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, meteorite

iam using Meteor Framwork (PREVIEW 0.7.1.2), i have installed bootstrap-3 using mrt, everything is working fine ,however from the console in chrome iam recieving this warning :

```
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf".
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg".
```

which is very annoying specially when developing for the console,

anyone have a fix for that ?
Thanks

Comment: When you click on http://localhost:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg or any other links, does the browser download it?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the path from the bootstrap-3 package, so you should be good to go.  Can you confirm that it is the package located [here](https://github.com/mangasocial/meteor-bootstrap-3) by mangasocial?

Answer (score 5):

Your fonts need to be served from the public folder in a Meteor application. In order to do this, you can create a symbolic link inside the public folder to wherever the fonts are located in your bootstrap installation.

**Edit:**
I downloaded the package you're using and checked the path to the fonts folder, use the code below to create a symbolic link to the fonts.  **Note** this must be run in your project's public directory.

```
ln -s ../packages/bootstrap-3/fonts ./
```

Comment: You're more or less right but you don't yet know which exact package is being used for this question, therefore your path is probably incorrect. You should communicate with the question author to get that information and reflect it in your answer.

Comment: @SerkanDurusoy you're right, I've made that edit and commented on the question to confirm that I got the correct package.  Thanks!

Comment: I simply moved my fonts folder from the theme I bought in to the public folder - and BOOM it worked like a charm. Thanks for the information. I suppose your symbolic link works too, rather than having 2 places different files.